# Trying to clean up iOS OAuth code

Tags: ios, networking, oauth, objective-c-blocks, flickr

I'm adding the ability to upload images to Flickr in my app. I'm using ObjectiveFlickr and using the SnapAndRun example code, and have it working. The only problem is, it just seems so ugly.

I rarely do much networking coding so this is a little tough to get in my head.

Authorizing my app with OAuth seems to be threaded through so many functions...there has to be a cleaner way.

I've thought about using blocks, but I don't have a good handle on it.

I basically have a 5 step process that starts in one function, sends some stuff out to Flickr which returns in another function and calls another function, and on and on...requesting tokens...waiting for a reply, putting up a webview confirmation...getting another token...more waiting...and finally hitting my upload code.

Has anyone done this a cleaner way? I'd love a little direction.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

I face same problem to authenticate with tumblr. And i found solution using oauth-consumer. You can download it from [git](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/ios-oauthconsumer) or [google-group](https://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer).

You have to register in flicker api in [here](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html) and you can get `CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` from there.

```
#define CONSUMER_KEY @"your consumer key here"
#define CONSUMER_SECRET @"your secret key here"
#define authorize_url  @"http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize"
#define request_token_url  @"http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token"

-(void)btnPressed:(id)sender{
    self.consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:CONSUMER_KEY secret:CONSUMER_SECRET];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:request_token_url];


    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                   consumer:self.consumer
                                                                      token:nil   // we don't have a Token yet
                                                                      realm:nil   // our service provider doesn't specify a realm
                                                          signatureProvider:nil]; // use the default method, HMAC-SHA1

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];

    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFinishWithData:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];
}

- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data {
    if (ticket.didSucceed)
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.accessToken= [[OAToken alloc] initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];

        NSURL *author_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:authorize_url,self.accessToken.key]];
        OAMutableURLRequest  *oaR = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:author_url consumer:nil token:nil realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];
        UIWebView  *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:webView];
        webView.delegate=self;
        [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
        [webView loadRequest:oaR];

    }
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSString *url = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSString *keyOne = @"oauth_token";
    NSString *keyTwo = @"oauth_verifier";
    NSRange r1 =[url rangeOfString:keyOne];
    NSRange r2 =[url rangeOfString:keyTwo];
    if (r1.location!=NSNotFound && r2.location!=NSNotFound) {
        // Extract oauth_verifier from URL query
        NSString* verifier = nil;
        NSArray* urlParams = [[[request URL] query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        for (NSString* param in urlParams) {
            NSArray* keyValue = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString* key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"oauth_verifier"]) {
                verifier = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];
                break;
            }
        }
        if (verifier) {
            NSURL* accessTokenUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token"];
            OAMutableURLRequest* accessTokenRequest =[[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:accessTokenUrl
                                                                                     consumer:self.consumer
                                                                                        token:self.accessToken
                                                                                        realm:nil
                                                                            signatureProvider:nil];
            OARequestParameter* verifierParam =[[OARequestParameter alloc] initWithName:@"oauth_verifier" value:verifier];
            [accessTokenRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [accessTokenRequest setParameters:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:verifierParam,nil]];
            OADataFetcher* dataFetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
            [dataFetcher fetchDataWithRequest:accessTokenRequest
                                     delegate:self
                            didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicketForAuthorization:didFinishWithData:)
                              didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenTicket:didFailWithError:)];
        } else {
            // ERROR!
        }
        [webView removeFromSuperview];
        return NO;
    }
    if([url isEqualToString:@"http://www.elegantmedia.com.au/"]){
        [webView removeFromSuperview];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}


- (void)requestTokenTicketForAuthorization:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFinishWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (ticket.didSucceed)
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        self.accessToken = [self.accessToken initWithHTTPResponseBody:responseBody];
        accessTokenKey=self.accessToken.key;
        accessTokenSecret=self.accessToken.secret;
        //[self post];

        NSString *blogUrl=(NSString *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tumblrBlogUrl"];
        if([blogUrl isEqualToString:@""]||blogUrl==nil){
            [self getUserInfo];
        }
        else{
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picture" ofType:@"jpg"]];
            [self postPhoto:data caption:@"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when" inBlog:blogUrl];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *responseBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response = %@",responseBody);
    }


}
- (void)requestTokenTicket:(OAServiceTicket *)ticket didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error = %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

If it need any additional parameters you can get from [here](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html).

Comment: THanks. I'm going to give this a try. It already looks a lot cleaner.

Comment: Some properties or instance variables are missing from your generous code posting. I could use a little help. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

[Flickr guidelines for OAuth](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html) seem pretty clear, but there's a github project [Flickr iOS OAuth](https://github.com/josephstein/Flickr-OAuth-iOS) if you want to see an example.